# Allow IP address without authentication

Tags: authentication, .htaccess

I have set up a site that is currently work in progress. I'm using an external SMS gateway that needs access to a script on my server. However, I have set up a basic username and password authentication for regular users, but the SMS gateway can't get through that.

How can I allow a single IP to pass through the authentication without authenticating itself, and deny all other users that aren't authenticated?

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.site_htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
require user admin
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of Apache 2.4, `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Satisfy` directives [should not be used anymore](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html#authz). So the new syntax is:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.site_htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"

<RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 44):

Just found out, with help from JoseK:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.site_htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
require valid-user
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Satisfy Any
```

Comment: What Apache and mod_auth version is that for?

Comment: This should work for Apache 2.2. Apache 2.4 has [new syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27209938/878514).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing first 2 lines to

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.x
```

Replace your desired IP in the `Allow from`

Comment: This just gives me an 403 Forbidden :/

Comment: Never mind that, I had an error.. :P BUT, now it just keeps asking me for authentication, and don't want to authenticate me when I enter my credentials.