# Apache basic authentication except for those Allowed

Tags: apache, authentication, basic-authentication

Problem: I have some files under /var/www/files/ that I want them to be accessed from specific IP addresses WITHOUT requiring user/password. However, I would like that any other IP address SHOULD require login to gain access.

This is in my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/files/>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168 
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/basic.pwd 
        AuthName "Please enter username and password" 
        AuthType Basic 
        Require user valid-user 
</Directory>
```

But, if I understood correctly, this means that any client coming from 192.168.* will have access to that directory BUT will require a valid-user to view its content. And any other IP address will be denied. right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Deny all is wrong syntax isn't it?  I had to use "Deny From All"

Comment: Yes you are right. I will fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**edit**: this may be accepted answer, but old. For new Apache installs, use [Brians answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27209938/358679)

Add this: `Satisfy Any` (which means either of those 2 should be passed).

And the syntax is either:

```
Require valid-user
```

Or:

```
Require user <userid>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it!. Here is the link for those who are interested: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy

Answer (score 68):

This is how it's done for Apache 2.4+ (since `Satisfy Any` is no longer supported).

```
<Directory /var/www/files/>

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/files/.htpasswd

    <RequireAny>
      Require ip 22.33.44.55
      Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>

</Directory>
```

If you want to require both IP address -and- Login/Password, change `<RequireAny>` to `<RequireAll>`

I hope this helps someone - as it took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Wow! This should be more popular. This was hard to find for an answer! I wonder if this is possible by Hostname rather than IP.

Comment: To use hostname instead of IP, use this format : Require host example.com

Comment: for Apache 2.2.x, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419592/htaccess-htpasswd-bypass-if-at-a-certain-ip-address)

Comment: I needed to add "Require all denied" before <RequireAny> in order for this to deny all other users (think this substitutes the depreciated "Deny from all" ?)

Comment: Wow. It's so clean! Thanks. (Note that if you want to allow an entire range of IP addresses, say... `Everyone in your office`, you can do it with `Require ip 22.33.44.0/255.255.255.0`. See: https://serverfault.com/a/682493/586831

Answer (score 6):

If your server is behind a proxy, you can't rely on the `Require ip` directly. However, you can use the [`Require env`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqenv):

```
<Directory /var/www/files/>

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/files/.htpasswd

    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "22.33.44.55" AllowIP

    <RequireAny>
      Require env AllowIP
      Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>

</Directory>
```

[The source of the idea](https://freistil.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201084275-How-can-I-restrict-IP-addresses-in-htaccess-with-the-reverse-proxy-in-front-)

Answer (score 4):

At Apache 2.4+, if you also like to set a fixed username based on the IP block you could use [AuthBasicFake](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#AuthBasicFake) directive together with runtime [If](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#If) directive.

This example with grant direct access to `22.33.44.55/32` and `66.77.88.99/32` and sets username `demouser`, all others must login.

```
<Location>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please enter your username and password"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/files/.htpasswd

    <If "-R '22.33.44.55/32' || -R '66.77.88.99/32'">
        AuthBasicFake demouser
        Require all granted
    </If>
    <Else>
        Require valid-user
    </Else>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "192.168.135.159" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "192.168.135.135" AllowIP

AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/domain.com/cms/.htpasswd"

<RequireAll>
Require env AllowIP
require valid-user
</RequireAll>
```

İ also checked many variants. this code üorks with 2.4 version of apache 100%