# .htaccess / .htpasswd bypass if at a certain IP address

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, basic-authentication

Is it possible to have an .htaccess/.htpasswd access control setup for a given directory, but if they are from a specific IP address, bypass the login/password authentication?

I know you can do something like this in the .htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 000.000.000.000
```

But if you add something along these lines:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Then it prompts for the password. Is there any way to do an if/else type setup, or some other solution so that users as a given IP (or set of IPs) don't get prompted for a password, but everyone else does?

Comment: Which apache version are you running?

Comment: Anyone have any solutions for Apache 2.2.x?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For versions 2.2.X you can use the following...

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
satisfy any
```

Obviously replace the path to your usersfile and the ip address which you would like to bypass the authentication.

Further explanation of the specifics, can be found at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 25):

If you use apache >=2.4, it would be something like this:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '127.0.0.1'">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "restricted area"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

For more info take a look at the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like the server is running Apache 2.2.19

Comment: Works perfectly for me (Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)). Thanks !

Comment: You can also use network notation instead of literal addresses: `<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '192.168.1.0/24'">`

Answer (score 17):

I am running Apache/2.2.16 (Debian), and had a similar problem, I solved it like this:

(This can be run in both an .htaccess file or directly in the virtualhost under `<Location/>`)

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/somesite/.htpasswd
AuthName "No entry, unless"
Require Valid-user
Allow from x.x.x.x
Allow from x.x.x.x
Satisfy Any
```

I allowed entry without password from two different ip, and the rest must enter password to enter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying this inside a `<Directory` block, which doesn't work, the `<Location />` part helped me out a great deal.

Comment: works for 2.4 as well, thanks

Answer (score 17):

Apache 2.4 compatible:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"

<RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

See the migration guide [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html#access) for more examples.

Comment: This one works best for me in apache 2.4.x and is a life saver, given that I've a lot of IPs to Require (about 60 ip ranges) o its a way better syntax than the one from NicoMinsk with the if/elseIf/else

Answer (score 7):

If you use apache >=2.4, and you want to allow a set of IP, as asked in initial question, you can do it like this :

```
   <If "-R '192.168.0.0/24'">
            Require all granted
    </If>
    <ElseIf "-R '192.168.1.0/24'">
            Require all granted
    </ElseIf>
    <Else>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "restricted area"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
    </Else>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of j5Dev:

```
# Interne IP-Adressen
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^127\.0\.0\.1$" IsIntern
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^192\.168" IsIntern
# .. add more IP addresses or ranges here

# Authentication, wenn nicht intern
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=IsIntern
satisfy any
```

Comment: None of the answers on this page work for me with the "satisfy any" directive, which is probably pretty important :) Is there anything else that needs configuring? I am on Apache 2.2.22.