# How to enable HTTP-based authentication requests only through the external ip?

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have apache server on ubuntu 12.04 with virtual hosts and router forwarded 80 port to one of them. The directory is configured http-authentication. I need to provide authentication for the requests only when a request comes in the "outside", that is, only when the request comes through the external ip, and if I call from inside the network (or from the server at localhost), no authentication is required.

Thanks in advance for your help. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `allow from` directive in conjunction with your http authentication directives in your httpd.conf file (or .htaccess file) to specify a range of IP addreses for which http authentication will not be required.  See [.htaccess / .htpasswd bypass if at a certain IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419592/htaccess-htpasswd-bypass-if-at-a-certain-ip-address) for more info.  Just specify your range of inside ip addresses in the `allow from` directive.