# .htaccess - Allow IP range with authentication & bypass for one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm struggling with a .htaccess file to accomplish the following:

I have a subdomain with our admin console in

- Grant access to /pagecheck/ from any IP without authentication (health check script)
- Block access to all other resources from any IP that is not on our list of approved IPs
- Request HTTP authentication popup for any allowed IPs

I'm struggling to block access from "outside" IPs as I can't seem to get the reordering right.

This is the code that works for /pagecheck/ and authentication:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/pagecheck/" noauth

AuthName "Admin Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/production/.htpasswd
require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=noauth
Satisfy any
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
Options -Indexes
```

However, I'm struggling to get the logic in the right place to only allow access from our office IP address range. I think it is conflicting with the different Orders and the authentication.

Could anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Add another `ALLOW` directive for your IP range, and switch `SATISFY` from `ANY` to `ALL`?

Comment: (Or, the Apache 2.4+ way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27209938/1427878)