# How to exclude some IPs from authorization

Tags: apache, apache2

I have following rule:

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName test-server
    Require valid-user
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd
</Location>
```

But want to exclude some IP addresses from authorisation process, so if you are connecting from such address, you don't have to submit login/password. How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow IP address without authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649852/allow-ip-address-without-authentication)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName test-server
    Require valid-user
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd
    Deny from all
    Allow from 123.123.123.123
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

Comment: You can also use a network mask to allow a subnetwork. For example: "Allow from 192.168.100.0/24" would allow all IPs from 192.168.100.1 to 192.168.100.254

Comment: how to Allow for website names? @Rabi