# Deny all IPs except 1 and require login for others

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, ip-address

I have a server which I would like only accessible via my IP address AND require authentication (either HTTP or PHP) for any users outside the IP address.

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 12.345.67.78
```

Any ideas on how to require some sort of authentication for users outside of home IP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow IP address without authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649852/allow-ip-address-without-authentication)

Comment: @Anigel Not really since I am looking for authentification

Comment: Which is exactly what the accepted answer does. Authentication from everyone except a specified IP, who does not need to authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_setenvif` in conjunction with `mod_auth`.

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^12\.345\.67\.78$ ALLOWED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
```