# Is it possible to add a plugin to chromedriver under a protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, end-to-end

I've been trying to handle the basic authentication during my protractor test. Some hard time on it, so i've found a chrome plugin wich sends automatically my credentials for websites that require basic authentication.

As each time that chromedriver is executed, a new profile is loaded, how can i permanelty add a plugin to my tests? I know that there is https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions, but i dont think this very clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure `extensions` list inside [`chromeOptions`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f56d850bafb25bbc9851709fab1d892ea59d11f0/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options):

```
capabilities {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'extensions': ['base64 encoded extension']
    }
}
```

Note that it in `extensions`, it is important to provide a [list of base-64 encoded packed Chrome extension](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-List-of-recognized-capabilities).

To get a *base64 encoded extension*, you need to read the `.ctx` extension file and encode the contents with `base64`. For example, using python:

```
>>> import base64
>>> data = open('path_to_the_ctx_extension').read()
>>> base64.standard_b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')
# outputs the encoded chrome extension which you can paste in the config
```

Or, easier, make a `helper.js` file using `fs` and `q`:

```
var q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.getCapabilities = function (filename) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        var capabilities = {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {
                extensions: [
                    data.toString('base64')
                ]
            }
        };
        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then, in your protractor config, use this `getCapabilities()` function to get capabilities:

```
var helper = require('./helper.js');

exports.config = {

    capabilities: helper.getCapabilities('/path/to/crx/extension'),

    ...
}
```

Currently, it works with a single extension, so there is a room for improvement.

Also, look through the following issue in case you have problems:

- [Setting Chrome Options](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/175)

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful! But i'm having an issue with this solution. As i set the path to my desired .crx and run my test, it fails, and no error message is being displayed. Just `Process finished with exit code 100`. I also read the thread you suggested me, but haven't found a solution for my case.

Comment: It doesnt provide a stacktrace. This is pretty much everything: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js C:\Users\QARJ\WebstormProjects\ProtractorPiloto\config.js
Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.44.130:61384/wd/hub

Process finished with exit code 100`

Comment: @andrepm and what if you omit the `extensions`? Is it running? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i tried to comment `extensions` and the extension path itself. In both ways, my test run normally.

Comment: @andrepm interesting, could you give the name of the extension? I'll try to reproduce the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @alecxe I tried it; getting this error in console
`[14:34:20] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
    at TypeError (native)`

Comment: So once you add the extension to chrome options. How do you interact with the extension?

Answer (score 7):

Check this: https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor/blob/master/bin/elementexplorer.js#L194

Here I am loading an extension from a local directory. The extension is not a crx file, but the uncompressed version.

```
'chromeOptions': {
  'args': ['--load-extension=' + extensionPath]
}
```

Comment: It didnt worked for me. It is like this? `'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--load-extension=' + 'C:/Users/QARJ/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/dgpgkkfheijbcgjklcbnokoleebmeokn/1.1_0']
        }`

Comment: Maybe the space in User Data is causing you trouble. Can you copy the extension to C:/tmp to test?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Happy testing! Also, check out my elementor tool: https://www.npmjs.org/package/elementor I am looking for feedback

Comment: Hi @andrepm, so this is the working solution? Out of curiosity, why is the other answer marked as the accepted answer?

Comment: Hi, both solutions are working. The other one is marked just because it was the first one.

Comment: @AndresD Facing issues; can you please take a look here. Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605385/unable-to-load-chrome-extension-in-protractor-tests

Comment: Link is dead? https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor/blob/master/bin/elementexplorer.js

Comment: Is it possible to include more than one extension using this method?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of committing the extension with your code and having to load it from disk when you run the tests you might want to consider using the [`authenticator-browser-extension`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/authenticator-browser-extension) Node module I have recently open-sourced.

To use the module install it from npm:

```
npm install --save-dev authenticator-browser-extension
```

And import in the `protractor.conf.js`:

```js
const { Authenticator } = require('authenticator-browser-extension');

exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',

        chromeOptions: {
            extensions: [
                Authenticator.for('username', 'password').asBase64()
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

**Pro tip**: remember not to commit your credentials with your code, consider using env variables instead.

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: Looks like this should be the accepted solution in 2019. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that it's useful!

Comment: This works fine with chrome. But fails to work with headless chrome. Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Headless Chrome doesn't support extensions https://www.npmjs.com/package/authenticator-browser-extension#chrome-headless , so you might need to use something like the BrowserMob Proxy - https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/