# Protractor not working in google chrome

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor testing tool in angular js, I installed CORS extension 
in chrome browser, I wrote my first test-case, I try to run this using
'protractor config.js' chrome browser is getting open, actually it is login form, i entered correct username and password but it is not connecting to server, I understood that CORS extension was disabled, how to enable cors extension when i am running test case through cmd.

my config.js

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
          // You can use other browsers
          // like firefox, phantoms, safari, IE (-_-)


            'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    specs: [
           // We are going to make this file in a minute
        '../www/modules/user/login.spec.js',
        //'../www/modules/lead/list.spec.js',

    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        //defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        isVerbose: true,
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
    onPrepare: function(){
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100/');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, a completely clean browser is fired up with no extensions installed.

In order to start Chrome with an extension, you need to set the `chromeOptions` and the `extensions` appropriately. Here you can find working samples:

- [Is it possible to add a plugin to chromedriver under a protractor test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278222/is-it-possible-to-add-a-plugin-to-chromedriver-under-a-protractor-test/27278322#27278322)

Comment: Thank u  , I got it now, finally

Comment: capabilities: {
          // You can use other browsers
          // like firefox, phantoms, safari, IE (-_-)
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--disable-web-security']
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

just change capabilities section. or u can follow alexe answer.

```
    capabilities: {
              // You can use other browsers
              // like firefox, phantoms, safari, IE (-_-)


                'browserName': 'chrome',
                 chromeOptions': { 'args': ['--disable-web-security'] }
        },
```