# Is it possible to click the chrome generated "Add Extension" modal using Selenium and Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, protractor

I am working on an angular web app that works in conjunction with a chrome extension. While trying to test the installation of the extension (using protractor) I have become blocked. I cannot find anything on clicking the chrome generated modal (see example attachment) to install the extension. Any insight?

[image: Example of the type of modal tat I am baffled by]

Answer (score 2):

No, this dialog is *out of Selenium's and hence Protractor's control*. What you can do is to start Chrome with pre-loaded extension. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278322/771848) for additional information.

Or/and, you can disable the popup and allow Chrome to install extensions silently without a prompt via the [`--prompt-for-external-extensions` flag](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#prompt-for-external-extensions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have preloading the extension covered. I am actually testing the web app launching the "install extension" modal and seeing whether or not it has been installed after the click. pre-loading it defeats the purpose of the test.

Comment: @TheCulprit gotcha, then, you can avoid this popup altogether and allow silent installation of an extension, updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: That might meet my needs. Thanks for the help!