# Unable to load Chrome extension in Protractor tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, protractor

Given below is a snippet from config.js

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['--load-extension=' + '/Users/prashanthsams/Downloads/addon.crx']
    }
  },
```

[image]

Note: I am able to install the .crx extensions manually through Chrome UI and not through automation

Comment: In my experience manifest file errors occur if there is a version mismatch or its incompatible, check you .crx extension is compatible or not!

Comment: @RamPasala I tried many .crx extensions, results are the same :(

Comment: @PrashanthSams check path of the extension. Start from driver C:\Users\prashanthsams\Downloads\addon.crx

Comment: @I.P  I use MAC and tats y my path differs; I believe no issues with path as it takes the .crx file.