# Setting up chrome extension path in protractor test

Tags: protractor

I want to load extension in my protractor test and do not want to point on my local computer for the .crx file.

I want to load a chrome extension with a .crx file . It works when i point to my local computer. But this will not work if i run my tests on a VM,

Here is what i am using :

```
   '--load-extension=' +
    '/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/obaimkjjkigcd/1.0.2_1/'
```

Please assist.

Comment: Please see [ask]. This site works best if you tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. It is not a great tutorial site for finding out how to invoke a framework like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a plugin to chromedriver under a protractor test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278222/is-it-possible-to-add-a-plugin-to-chromedriver-under-a-protractor-test)

Comment: This doesn't seem the same problem i am facing.