# Have modified with the recommended protractor.conf.js but still not able to bypass basic authenticator

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, serenity-js, testautomationfx

Thanks for providing the solution with regards to the fix to popup credential ([PreviousPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278222/is-it-possible-to-add-a-plugin-to-chromedriver-under-a-protractor-test/62409184?noredirect=1#comment110379174_62409184)). I have attempted to do the same thing too on my Protractor.conf.js

```js
const {
  Authenticator
} = require('authenticator-browser-extension');
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      extensions: [
        Authenticator.for('username', 'password').asBase64()
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

However, when I tried to execute my script, I am still not able to 'bypass' the basic authentication.
I have used chromedriver with version 83.

Regards, Vic Lim

Edited
I have attached the scrrenshot of the popup below for your reference. I have also tried to use browser.switchto().alert().authenticateas(), but the script says this is not an alert.

[image: s]