# .htaccess 403 Fobidden (IP on whitelist)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

In Magento I have added my IP to exclusion list in the .htaccess., however I still  see 403 Forbidden page when I load the site. But if I change to "allow from all" the page loads fine.

```
order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 111.222.333.44
```

Assume 111.222.333.44 is my IP

Why my IP is not recognized ?

Appreciate all responses.

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: I am running Apache 2.2.24

Comment: check the IP address is that of your own computer and not the IP address of the server (just checking you haven't got mixed up)

Comment: Did you enable `htpasswd` authentication for your website? if yes, you should use this link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650673/1906322

Comment: Good point, but in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your apache access logs and confirm if you can see your IP address there (there might be a proxy between the client and apache which will hide the real client IP)

Comment: Problem solved. There were restriction on my server side. Since router IP is dynamic the newly generated IP was blocked by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. But the error may happen for your server fault. Try this another server may work.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html

order deny,allow
deny from all

allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Comment: Tried, does help, still 403 Forbidden error. It's just really strange that it allows form all, but my IP doesn't allow. and I restarted router several times.

Comment: you can write a iptable rules if you are using any linux server. Let me know i you do that  @Icon